# make new array from existing array based on a delimiter in php

Tags: php, arrays, delimiter

I am working at a login script in which the username is an email address and the user can have more than 1 email address with which he can login.

I am creating an array based on a MySQL select LIKE because all the email addresses of the user are on the same column having `##` as delimiters.

```
Array (
    [0] => test@yahoo.com 
    [1] => testabc@yahoo.com##test123@yahoo.com 
    [2] => testing@yahoo.com##abcd@yahoo.com
)
```

I would like to obtain this array so I can then compare the user input with the exact email address:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => test@yahoo.com 
    [1] => testabc@yahoo.com 
    [2] => test123@yahoo.com 
    [3] => testing@yahoo.com 
    [4] => abcd@yahoo.com
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can use `explode()` to obtain the array of email addresses.

Comment: How about splitting it on the PHP-side i.e. `$arrMail= explode('##', $row['mail']);`. I would strongly advise to rewrite your user database instead of storing emails in this way.

Comment: If a user can have multiple email addresses registered, they need to be in a separate table. Separating data with delimiters in a single column is usually a bad idea.

Comment: although using delimiters and storing email addresses this way may not be a good solution maybe using three dots (...) as a delimiter could be better instead of ## because i read that repetition of character dot is not allowed in email addresses. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr = array(); //your array, your values.
$arrGonnaBe = array(); 
foreach($arr as $a){

    $exp = explode("##",$a);
    if(count($exp)>1){
        foreach($exp as $e){
            array_push($arrGonnaBe,$e);
        }
    }else{
        array_push($arrGonnaBe,$exp[0]);
    }
} 
print_r($arrGonneBe);
?>
```